# 100% height iFrame in Custom Receiver?

Tags: html, css, iframe, chromecast

I have a Custom Receiver(CR) for my Chromecast(CC) application and need to make an iFrame 100% height.

I have the width set to 100% and that works, but despite defining the height as 100%, it seems to only be about 1/3rd the height (of the screen)

Any ideas on how to achieve a full height iFrame?

Code below:

HTML:

```
<iframe id="container"frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit tricky, since the default setting of the height is not 100% (in body, html tags) so all you have to do is set html & body tags to 100% like this:

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6yqsro9/4/